# Sharing tradingview drawing objects with other users

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

since i use some specific price levels and zones in my trading , I want to share them with my friends. Is there possibility to do so with some kind of indicator or Tradingview API? The best way for me would be to fill in some table and they would be able to import (or use indicator to do so) and see all zones and levels for different instruments on their charts. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to export your settings or plots to an external file as a eg. json that you can share.
The most straightforward way is to right your own indicator/strategy/library that you can publish - the way you want open/protected/invite-only (for premium only), although it is difficult. [Reference](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Publishing.html?highlight=publishing)

The best solution for you may lie under your layout settings on your chart described by Tradingview [here](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000606515-how-to-share-charts-in-view-only-mode/).
[image: TradingView share] *img reference: [TradingView](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn.freshdesk.com/data/helpdesk/attachments/production/43178220293/original/SQwvOvlS6uPfmiGPMAtF69mIK1O-0Ramdg.png?1606999603)*